# Python - splitting string into individual bytes and putting them back together

Tags: python, sockets, split, chat, p2p

Here is a part of a python script I have:

```
  textString = raw_input('')
  text = list(textString)
  print textString
      try:
          for i in range (0, len(text)):
              chat_client.sock.send(text[i])
              i = i + 1
          chat_client.sock.send(0)
          except:
              Exception
          try:
              for i in range (0, len(text)):
                  chat_server.conn.send(text[i])
                  i = i + 1
              chat_server.conn.send(0)
          except:
              Exception
```

I then am hoping to put it back together when it is received, using the int delimiter 0.  Just for testing purposes, I have got:

```
                    byte = self.conn.recv(1024)
                    if byte:
                        print byte
                    else:
                        break
```

just to show each byte that has been received individually.

However, when I insert a string, some of it is split into more than one character:
e.g. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog -->

```
T 
h 
e  
q 
u 
i 
ck 

b 
r 
o 
wn 

f 
ox j 
umps ov 
er the  
lazy dog
```

I wondered if anyone could figure out why this might be going on.

Thank you in advance.

Also, in case you are wondering why I am trying to split text like this, it is due to a suggestion from this post:
[Python P2P socket chat script - only fully working on home network; connects at school but does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174433/python-p2p-socket-chat-script-only-fully-working-on-home-network-connects-at?noredirect=1#comment41045910_26174433)

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: @NPE thank you for pointing that out.  It's fixed on the actual python file but, for some reason, it has reformatted here.  I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is *by design* on stream socket. From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_socket) : *a stream socket is a type of internet socket which provides a connection-oriented, sequenced, and unique flow of data without record boundaries*. If multiple messages are already present when you read, they may be concatenated.

All what is guaranteed by the specification, if that you get all, and in order.